# Как сделать чтобы бот првоерял по списку

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Есть список, бот проверяет ник пользователя и сверяет со списком, если ник пользователя есть в списке, то бот даёт ему роль. У меня бот проверяет весь список и отправляет несколько сообщений. Надо чтобы бот проверил весь список, дал роль и написал одно сообщение. Как это можно исправить? Ниже мой код и скрин ошибки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то вот решение:

```
for item in data:
    a1 = item["nickname"]
    if ctx.message.author.nick == a1:
        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send('Удачной игры')
        break
else:
    await ctx.send('Вы не в списке')
```

Совет: Когда задаёте вопрос нужно вставлять код текстом, а не картинкой.